# How to provide 14 float values per vertex to the shader?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I have downloaded a model, and have exported it as `.fbx`. The model contains several animations (6 to be precise), and I want to have one of them displayed. Following  [Anton Gerdelan's book on openGL](http://antongerdelan.net/opengl/) I wrote an importer, which uses assimp to parse the model, buffers the relevant vertex data and retrieves the offset matrices needed for the animation.

Not having much experience with skeletal animation, I **think** I've been able to make the necessary changes to anton's importer, so that it can work on the more complex model that I need. However, the importer assumes that each vertex is only influenced by 1 bone, which unfortunately is not the case.

After some tinkering, I figured out that each vertex of the model can be influenced by at most 14 bones at a time. Since I am not sure how I could pass 14 values to the shader containing `boneId` and the relevant `weight` I tried changing the code to accommodate up to 4 bones at a time. This is the code that parses the bone id & weights and buffers them:

```
    *bone_count = (int)mesh->mNumBones;
    char bone_names[256][64];

    struct vertexdata {
        int IDs[4];
        float Weights[4];
        int ptr;
    };

    vector<vertexdata> vdata;
    vdata.resize(*point_count);

    for (int i = 0; i < *point_count; i++) {
        vdata[i].ptr = 0;
    }

    for (int b_i = 0; b_i < *bone_count; b_i++) {
        const aiBone* bone = mesh->mBones[b_i];
        strcpy(bone_names[b_i], bone->mName.data);
        printf("bone_names[%i]=%s\n", b_i, bone_names[b_i]);
        bone_offset_mats[b_i] = convert_assimp_matrix(bone->mOffsetMatrix);

        //getting weights for each bone
        int num_weights = (int)bone->mNumWeights;
        for (int w_i = 0; w_i < num_weights; w_i++) {
            aiVertexWeight weight = bone->mWeights[w_i];

            int vid = weight.mVertexId;
            float vweight = weight.mWeight;

            if (vdata[vid].ptr < 4) {
                vdata[vid].IDs[vdata[vid].ptr] = b_i;
                vdata[vid].Weights[vdata[vid].ptr] = vweight;
                vdata[vid].ptr++;
            }


            int vertex_id = (int)weight.mVertexId;
        }

    }


    //buffering bone id data
    GLuint vbo1;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo1);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo1);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vdata[0]) * vdata.size(), &vdata[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(3);
    glVertexAttribIPointer(3, 4, GL_INT, sizeof(vertexdata), (const GLvoid*)0);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(4);
    glVertexAttribPointer(4, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(vertexdata), (const GLvoid*)16);
```

and in the shaders:

vertex shader

```
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 pos;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 norm;
layout (location = 2) in vec2 UV;
layout (location = 3) in ivec4 boneIDs;
layout (location = 4) in vec4 Weights;

uniform mat4 view, projection, model;
uniform mat4 bone_matrices[40];

out vec2 tCoords;

void main()
{
    mat4 boneTransform = bone_matrices[boneIDs[0]] * Weights[0];
    boneTransform += bone_matrices[boneIDs[1]] * Weights[1];
    boneTransform += bone_matrices[boneIDs[2]] * Weights[2];
    boneTransform += bone_matrices[boneIDs[3]] * Weights[3];

    tCoords = UV;
    gl_Position = projection * view * boneTransform * model  * vec4(pos, 1.0);
}
```

fragment shader

```
#version 330 core

in vec2 tCoords;
out vec4 fragColour;

uniform sampler2D tex;

void main()
{   
    fragColour = texture(tex, tCoords); 
}
```

The model is rendered properly, but I am not observing any movement. Again, not knowing much about skeletal animation, I can only assume that it's because I haven't included every bone that influences each vertex, and the corresponding weight. However, when buffering the data the shaders only accept up to `vec4` aka 4 values per vertex. How can I pass 14 IDs and 14 weights? Could this be the cause of the animation not working?

Comment: 14 floats equals three vec4 and one vec2. Or you use uniform buffers which allow arbitrary sized arrays.

Comment: Hey you read from a lot of places from your buffer layout (look at vertex shader) but you only have one vertex attribute pointer. (Look at "buffering bone id data") i suggest that this is your problem

Comment: @BDL so  `glVertexAttribIPointer(3, 14, ...)` would amount to 3 `vec4`s and a `vec2`?

Comment: No. But you can bind the first 4 floats to one vec4 attribute, then the next four floats to another vec4 attribute and so on.

Comment: @tomerzeitune yes, i'm sorry for not mentioning, but i omitted the rest of the buffering because positions, texture coordinates, etc seem to be working fine

Comment: Do you have a code to re-draw, on idle or timer ?

Comment: @BDL Oh i see, please tell me your opinion, could this be the reason the model is not moving? I am out of ideas, if this fails as well

Comment: @VictorGubin would it help if i included the code that draws, during the main loop?

Comment: @VlassisFo this is actually idle method, i.e. before `glfwPollEvents`, `glfwWaitEvents` must not be used in this case.

Comment: @VictorGubin could you please clarify? I call `glfwPollEvents` just at the end of the mainloop, and I don't use `glfwWaitEvents`. Could this cause a problem?

Comment: @VlassisFo Check this [Putting it together](https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/quick.html#quick_example) should be the same.

Comment: BTW, `gl_Position = projection * view * boneTransform * model  * vec4(pos, 1.0);` is actually a bad practice to multiply matrices inside the shaders, this brings to bad performance. Vertex shader called for each vertex node, so you just wasting GPU time for operation should be done only once. You'd better multiply matrices on CPU, using [GLM](https://github.com/g-truc/glm) for example and then transfer only matrices you really need into shader as uniforms. i.e. something like `glPosition = mvp * bone * vec4(pos, 1.0)` as well as `uniform mat4 bone_matrices[40];` should be only 4, not 40.

Comment: @VictorGubin thanks for the tips, im still getting the hang of it. As for the `bone_matrices` they contain the transformations of each bone. The total bones are 40, so that's why i defined it like that. The other are merely 4 indices to the bone array (which need to be 14, not 4 but i'm facing technical difficulties...).